# Custom jQuery event listener that triggers on show()

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that gets hidden and displayed, via `.hide()` and `.show()`. When it is displayed by `.show()` I need it to do some stuff. Is there any way I can setup a custom event listener that fires a callback when the `div` goes from hidden to visible? I can make a function and call it wherever I would call `$(#myDiv").show()` but that happens in multiple places and I would like to keep this all in one place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a function callback into the show method which will execute after the show has completed:

```
$("#myDiv").show(function(){
   myCustomFunction();
});
```

Comment: This is wrong answer. According to jquery API, first argument always should be _duration_. See [link](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete).

Comment: @dnim - The duration argument (and callback argument) are both optional.  jQuery is smart enough to figure it out if you only pass in one.

Comment: That's not the question

Answer (score 2):

You could use you own function instead of the internal "show" with a specific callback.